# Aaron's sons and intoxication

Tags: kohen-priest, korban, mishkan-tabernacle, parashat-shemini, intoxication

One interpretation of the death of Aaron's sons is they were intoxicated while bringing alien incense offerings. The prohibition of a Kohen being intoxicated is given **after** this tragic event. My question is if this was indeed the reason for their deaths, how could they have known since the prohibition had not been revealed yet?

Comment: The Chizkuni says that it is not befitting that a drunk person should perform sacrificial services, especially a Kohen should not perform avodas Hashem while in a drunken state. So maybe that's why.

Comment: Yes as stated in the question that edict was not revealed until after the incident so how would they have known?

Comment: There are some things that are considered so basic that they need not be said. If they are said, then that means the situation is bad. For example, for most people it is obvious that murder is bad. But we still have laws against it, because it's not clear to everyone. This reflects a deep flaw in mankind. So too here. It should have been obvious that serving intoxicated was a no-no.

Comment: I'm not defending their actions by any stretch. I've read arguments that the brothers were TOO spiritual and that was their downfall. They were tzaddikim after all. Seems if something was so obvious then why was it necessary to be decreed AFTER the tragedy? They may have known it wasn't a proper state to be in but maybe they didn't suspect it was a transgression that would cost them their lives. Just pondering this.

Comment: @Ephraim77 I agree with Harel13. The prohibition might not have been given yet, but would that make their action a good thing?

Answer (score 1):

The משכיל לדוד writes, based on a Midrash brought down in Rashi (ויקרא ט״ז,א), that the actual warning of not drinking wine was given before, only the punishment wasn’t known yet

Answer (score 0):

A Hasidic rabbi that I have contact with gave a class on this subject one day and he said that the Rebbe explained that Aaron's two sons had a very high spirituality and wanted to stay as close to God as possible and they got what they wanted, the closest to God was in the holy sanctuary, because they drank wine and wine and in Hebrew it has numerical value 70 and 70 also has numerical value for secrets, mystical part, Kabbalah, so when wine enters secrets come out, as they were fair secrets come out of the Torah, unlike the evil inclination as in the case of Samson and Delilah, he got drunk on wine and revealed secrets he shouldn't reveal and that was the end of him. These two events are connected, one of the sons of Aaron Nadab was single, he said that there were no women at his level, after he died God reincarnated him in Samson and he ended up with a Philistine woman, while Nadab drank wine with Samson he couldn't because he was a Nazirite, that's how he ratified his mistake for not getting married, it was a punishment, Samson was from the tribe of Dan and was called Ben Dan, backwards Nadab, so he speaks.

Then God told Moses that it is not at any time that he will enter the holy sanctuary, only on Yom Kippur will he enter, Moses consoled Aaron by saying that his sons were greater than he, that when the tabernacle was ready a very strong light would come down and something very high would rise to counterbalance, he thought it would be either him or Aaron but it was his two sons, within the sacred I will sanctify myself said God.

Answer (score 0):

In HaYom Yom on Parashat Shemini based on Orach Chayim, they didn't die from punishment. They died from being "drunk on closeness to Hashem", which is something that became forbidden after that, i.e. getting so close to Hashem that one expires.

Comment: I.e. Ethan Leonard's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an excellent question. In a careful discourse on this topic, (*Likkutei Sichos, volume 12, Shemini 1*) the Lubavitcher Rebbe explains Rashi's view on this subject. There, Rashi on Vayikra, 10:2 quotes first a different explanation and then this one as reasons for why Aharon's sons died.

First, the Rebbe draws on a developed principle in Rashi that any answer containing two explanations does so because each is *insufficient* to explain all of the questions on the verse in the realm of pshat (non-esoteric understanding), but that the first quoted explanation best explains the pshat of the verse. That would mean that the explanation discussed in our topic here is already identified by Rashi as being further from pshat, yet still important in some way.

Then he uses two other principles and some close reading of Rashi to reach the following conclusions, which I'll summarize here:

The first explanation reads very well with the verses except

1. that an equivalent expression is used in their punishment to the adjacent episode of Divine investiture in the Mishkan, which suggests that there was something holy, at least in intent, about their action, and
2. that in Moshe's own estimation, Aharon's sons who were punished in this way are greater than himself and Aharon, suggesting that they did not commit a true sin.

Rashi therefore seems to understand that according to this first explanation, their service was in fact very holy, causing an investiture in the Mishkan, but they warranted the death penalty only because they were not commanded to perform it and did so anyways in front of their teacher Moshe. According to the first opinion (Rabbi Eliezer), this causes the Divine presence to *depart* , i.e. the opposite of investiture, from the Jewish people.

This last point is difficult to understand, because it leaves one issue unresolved: if their action caused a departure of the Divine presence, how come the same phrase is used with regard to their punishment as the one used with regards to the investiture of the Divine presence?

It is as a result of this difficulty alone that Rashi finds it important to bring the opinion of Rabbi Yishmael (discussed in our question here), because it implies that essentially, whatever they did wrong was not yet prohibited, and they didn't deserve much blame for it. That can explain how they could have caused a Divine investiture, since they were clean of any sin here and only pure-minded.

**In response** to the pointed, crucial question in our question above, regarding what they could even be guilty of at all, Rashi brings a Midrash (*Vayikrah Rabbah, 12:1*) discussing this case by way of an analogy. In short, it describes Aharon's sons as G-d's בני בית (literally "sons of the house", carrying the connotation of being within the inner circle), and that while anyone else might not have known that drinking wine in the Mishkan would have been inappropriate, they did (like Harel13 said in his comment to the question).

However, the Rebbe concludes that this answer is not sufficient. He says that it does not adequately explain why their punishment was so severe, and that Rashi himself tacitly points out this fact by quoting the name of the opinion's author within his commentary, which he only does when the author's character is relevant. In this case, the author is Rabbi Yishmael, who the Talmud (*Chullin 49a*) describes as "Kohen who aids other Kohanim", in reference to numerous attempts to find positive outlooks on aspects relating to the Kohanim, whether it be leniencies or minimizations of guilt, such as in this story. Rashi notices that this explanation leaves something to be desired in terms of the direct explanation of the verse, and attributes that  - to some degree - to the character of the author.

This serious difficulty leads it to be numbered as the second of Rashi's explanations, which as we have already mentioned, means that it is weaker than the first in the realm of pshat.

The question is validated in the realm of pshat, although in the deeper explanations of chassidut and kabbalah, there are rigorous answers. Among them  are:

1. Drinking "wine" refers to taking on "בינה" (*Eiruvin 63a*), which is a mindset wherein one chooses to evaluate, prioritize, and judge their service of G-d based on their own knowledge. In Chassidic parlance, this is described as "עבודה בהבנה והשגה", and it stands in direct contrast to the ביטול (humility) required of service in the Mishkan. In other words, the phrase "they entered the Mikdash *(here referring to the Mishkan of course)* having drunk wine" means that they entered with a plan to serve G-d that was intellectually advanced and properly thought out, but the fact that they had not actually been commanded to do it displayed a lack of humility which was unacceptable for such a holy place. (from the above Sicha)
2. The fact that Aharon's sons are described in such glowing terms by Moshe, that they seemed to cause an investiture of Divine presence as discussed above, and that they were given a primary role in instruction and service motivates answers like Rabbi Kaii's above. In Likkutei Sichos volume 31, Purim 2, the Rebbe uses our case to demonstrate that drinking wine can refer to a spiritual high in the form of profound Kabbalistic study, *but* that it **must** have also included actual wine - it can not only refer to a spiritual drunkenness. The proof for this is that the following verse forbids drinking physical wine, not excessive meditation. Aharon's sons drank wine to aid in their revelation of Torah secrets, which ended up causing a spiritual expiry.

Anyways, excellent pointed question with plenty of depth.

**Summary**:

---

The question is valid on a pshat level according to Rashi, although it's mitigated by the fact that they were considered part of G-d's inner circle, and therefore knew it was inappropriate before it was commanded. Rashi favors a different explanation for why they died because this one minimizes their wrongdoing too steeply for a pshat interpretation.

More esoteric readings of this interpretation describe their punishment as the result of either a display of arrogance in the Mishkan or as the result of unbalanced meditation, aided by wine.

---

I encourage seeing those discourses inside.

They're available at https://www.mafteiach.app/likkutei_sichos/by_volume/